Does this rule imply axiom of choice?
if $\kappa; \lambda$ are infinite Scott cardinals, then: $$2^\kappa = 2^\lambda \leftrightarrow 
  \kappa \leq \lambda < 2^\kappa  \lor \lambda \leq \kappa < 2^\lambda   $$
Would adding the above to axioms of $\sf ZF$ imply $\sf AC$?

By "Scott cardinal" do you mean you are identifying cardinalities with their representatives of minimal rank, or something else?

Nitpick: the phrase “Scott cardinals” makes your questions unnecessarily reliant on Foundation. It’s fine here to just have $\kappa, \lambda$ be arbitrary sets.

@AndrésE.Caicedo, Yes, the Scott cardinality of $x$ is the set of all sets equinumerous with $x$, of minimal rank. So a Scott cardinal is the Scott cardinality of some set.

@ElliotGlazer, True! But, after all I'm speaking within $\sf ZF$. To make it foundation independent we may take $\kappa, \lambda$ to be any arbitrary infinite sets, define exponentiation, and the cardinal comparison's directly on sets in terms of sets of all functions from the index (exponent) to the indexed, and in terms of injections\bijections in the usual manner.
